# Datatables postgres duplicate rows paging

Tags: php, postgresql, datatable

I'm using datatables plugin with postgres database. When I'm ordering columns I'm getting duplicate rows on some pages. For example:

When I'm sorting column "ASG" on first page:
[image]

And on the second page:
[image]

But when I'm sorting by Domain name (first column) everything is ok. Any ideas?

Here's my ssp.class file: https://github.com/guillermovil/datatables-postgres/blob/master/ssp.class.pg.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you use for the order-by are not unique. When reaching the 2nd page you are issuing a 2nd query and there is absolutely no guarantee that the rows are returned in the same sequence.

You would need to add a 2nd field to your sort, ideally one having unique values. It seems that the Domain Name field contains unique values so it is a good candidate (and this is why it works OK when sorting just by this field, as every query will return the rows in the same sequence).

Have a look at this [page](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) that gives a very detailed explanation of the issue.